# "Light reflects off mirror" in Chinese

Tags: translation

> Light reflects off mirror.

镜子反射光 or 光反射镜子, which is correct?

镜子反射光 is supporsed to be right. But it sounds strangely for me. How do you think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When ***light, heat, or other rays reflect off a surface*** or when a
>   surface reflects them, they are sent back **FROM** the surface and do not
>   pass through it.

“*Light reflects off mirror*.” means **光线从镜子反射出来/过来/回来/开来**. "**Off**" denotes the sense of '**from**' in this case.

Compared to this sentence:

> *The sun reflected off the snow-covered mountains. // 阳光从被雪覆盖的山峦反射回来。*

As a sidenote, from English perspective, maybe it's better to put:

> Light reflects off mirrors. Or, Light reflects off the/that mirror.

But I am not a native English speaker. It's all opinion-based. Hope some English native speakers can correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: ('The sun reflected off the snow-covered mountains. // 阳光从被雪覆盖的山峦反射回来。' ) means 'sun' itself not 'sunlight'

Comment: @TangHo Well, "the sun" can mean "the light and heat from the sun".

Answer (score 1):

Light (is) reflected off mirror = 光线被镜子反射

Mirror reflects light = 镜子反射光线

> *Definitions of reflect*
>
> *verb*
>
> *(of a surface or body) throw back (heat, light, or sound) without absorbing it.*

Mirror is the subject, light is the object